# Is there a "start" like "end" in fs.createreadstream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

I am using csv-parser library, and i want to check table captions before parsing them

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser')

fs.createReadStream('tes.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('start', start=>{
            console.log(start)
//here i should check how column names are captioned
        })
        .on('data', data=>{
            console.log(data)
//if they are captioned as requiered i do things
        })
```

I checked the documentation but didnt find anything about it, so there is something to use like .on('end', ()=>{})?
Or there is an other way to get column names?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't. My suggestion would be to simply use the first `data` event, using a `.once` call. In it, you then attach the `.on` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get column names with `headers` event. `csv-parser` emit `headers` event after header row parsed. First parameter of callback function is `Array[String]` and you can access column names or headers . ([more doc](https://github.com/mafintosh/csv-parser#headers-1))

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const csv = require('csv-parser')

fs.createReadStream('tes.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('headers', headers=>{
            console.log(headers)
        })
        .on('data', data=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
```

Comment: It is even better, thanks for answer